# Angular directive won't update boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my controller that toggles a class, and changes a value `$scope.logocollapsed` to *true* to hide elements. When I use `ng-click` to call the function it works as designed, the class is added and the value is set to true.

I made a directive to toggle the class, and change the value of `$scope.logocollapsed`, this is called on a scroll event, and it toggles the class, however it won't change the value of `$scope.logocollapsed`

Here is my directive:

```
                .directive('scrollspy', function () {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'A',
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            var raw = element[0];
                            console.log('loading directive');

                            element.bind( 'scroll', function() {
                                //console.log(raw.scrollTop);

                                if (! $('.sidebar-menu').hasClass('collapsed')){
                                    if (raw.scrollTop > 200) {
                                        scope.menuClose();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                })
```

Here is what it looks like inside of my controller.

```
$scope.menuClose = function(bool) {
 if(! $('.sidebar').hasClass('collapsed')) {
     $('.sidebar-menu').addClass('collapsed');
     $scope.logocollapsed == true;
 }
};
```

Again, I'm not sure why my directive is able to run the `menuClose()` function and handle the class, but it won't update the value to false.

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: `$scope.logocollapsed == true;` should be `$scope.logocollapsed = true;` (one equals sign instead of two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of problems.

- As mentioned in the other answer you are doing an equality comparison instead of assignment @`$scope.logocollapsed == true;`
- You must perform [`scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) in order to trigger the digest cycle manually inside the scroll event.

  `element.bind( 'scroll', function() {
          if (! $('.sidebar-menu').hasClass('collapsed')){
              if (raw.scrollTop > 200) {
                  scope.menuClose();
                  scope.$apply();
              }
          }
      });`
- It is not considered a good practice to perform DOM manipulation or explicit DOM access in controller. You should probably move that code `if(! $('.sidebar').hasClass('collapsed')) {...` to the directive linker function. and have the controller function only set the flag.

Comment: Thanks, the `scope.$apply();` did the trick. I did end up moving the logic over, it seems much better all around. There's a lot more info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) if anyone else runs into a similar issue.

Comment: @AndySanchez You are welcome. i will hook up the link in the answer. And as i said try to avoid placing any DOM specific logic i the controller.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the issue appears to be within `$scope.menuClose`.

This:

```
$scope.logocollapsed == true;
```

Should be this:

```
$scope.logocollapsed = true;
```

`==` is a comparison operator, whereas `=` is an assignment operator.